# Python: multiplying 'for i in range(..) iteration'

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have an assignment where I am required to return `inf` by multiplying `x` by 10 multiple times using a:

```
for i in range(...)
```

so the main part of my code is:

```
   def g(x):
      x = 10.*x
      for i in range(308):
          return x
```

and if I enter

```
    >>> g(3.)
    >>> 30.0
```

I expected it to iterate it 308 times to the point where I get `inf`. Is there a line I can use that uses the number in the `for i in range(..)` to iterate the equation that many times?  For example:

```
   def g(x):
       x = 2.*x
       for i in range(3):
       # the mystery line I need for it to work
           return x
   >>> g(4.)
   >>> 16.0
```

but it doesn't give me that. Rather it returns `8.0`

Another way I did it that actually made it work was using print. But I don't think it's valid using a print statement in an assignment asking to `return inf`.

Comment: You return on first iteration? What are you trying to do, and what do you expect a for loop with just a return to do?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is in the 2nd piece of code. And I know I'm missing something between the for loop and the return. That's why I'm a bit lost.

Comment: look at your loop. All it does is return, and return stops execution of current function and returns value to callee...

Comment: I'm guessing you want this: https://ideone.com/SgLz0S

Comment: the indented lines below the loop 'for i in range(3):' are executed for every value of i, but you have 'return' there, which terminates the loop. The mystery line is the line that should be repated... The return should be done after the loop, so put that on an unindented line

Comment: that worked thank you! So I understand what you mean now by the return comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right parts, just not arranged correctly. Try something like this:

```
def g(x):
      for i in range(308):
          x = 10.*x    # because we've moved this line into the loop, it gets run 308 times
      return x  # since we've unindented this line, it runs only once (after the loop ends)
```

The part you want to be repeated needs to be indented after the line with the `for` statement. Stuff you don't want repeated (like the `return`, which can only happen once), should not be in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't iterating like you expect is because of the `return` statement. `return` exits from whatever procedure/function that you are running immediately and returns the value given to it. Here is a walk through of your first function, assuming it was called with the value of `4` as in `g(4.)`.

```
# the start of the function
# x = 10

# this line sets x = 100. I think you can see why.
x = 10. * x

# this sets i = 0 and begins to loop
for i in range(308):

    # this IMMEDIATELY returns from the function with the value
    # of x. At this point, x = 100. It does not continue looping!
    # Without this line, i would be set to 1, 2, 3, ..., 307 as 
    # you loop through the range. This is why it worked with print.
    return x
```

What you want instead of this is something that will accumulate the value of the repeated multiplications. You don't want to return anything at all within the loop, assuming you want every iteration to run. I will not give you the exact answer because this is homework but I will give a hint. You probably do not want `return` to be indented, as it is in the second bit of code you provided. You probably want something more like this:

```
def g(x):
    x = 2 * x
    for i in range(3):
        # { your code here }
        # You want to accumulate the value!
    return x
```